# How to merge all scene geometry into a single mesh?

Tags: workflow, scene

I would like to have all the geometry of a scene merged in one mesh. It should include curves, fonts, group instances, particles, with applied modifiers, etc...
`obj.to_mesh` doesn't work for group instances for example.

Comment: Is this a question about scripting? you mention `obj.to_mesh` but don't include scripting in your tags.

Comment: Yes it was actually about scripting, but your answer on how to do it in viewport is also interesting for other people I guess. I add the Python tag

Comment: in that case I think there are better ways to do this then, also interested why you would need to do this?

Comment: The modifier stack has some limitation regarding order. I'm trying to shrinkwrap a mesh on another mesh that has an animated boolean and particles. Problem is the shrinkwrap applies after the boolean and gives strange/messy results as there is nothing to shrinkwrap on (2 modifier stacks, so...). Also particles disappear instantly too being spawned or not but in no way disappearing slowly like the rest. I guess the modifier Stack has to be changed to allow user to choose the order in which modifiers apply. In the meantime I didn't found another way (memory and time consuming but it works)

Comment: better than a long test, the file (without particles as my PC crash if I try to add one system to the displaced mesh): http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27520

Answer (score 13):

First make all duplis real, then convert all to mesh and join.

- Object -> Apply -> Make Duplicates Real
- Object -> Convert to -> Mesh *(This applies mesh modifiers too)*
- Select the base object to join into (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>)
- Object -> Join

Shorthand: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd> -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

---

*Note, You might want to first un-hide all objects, view all layers and make any linked data local too, thats if you want to apply to the entire scene and not just what you see.*

Comment: Works well, thanks for the Shorthand, like that :) @ideasman42 After usage of the method in real case, here are some remarks: Make duplicate real must sometime be done twice (dupligroups of objects with particles for example). Duplicates with lots of instances (1 000 000 of small spheres for example) won't convert in acceptable timeframe. Maybe add a warning (it may freeze the computer/crash Blender) in the answer until Blender get's better support of many objects.

Answer (score 1):

Select all objects with <kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd> then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join into one mesh.